# CONVERT MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM to DD/MM/YYYY in C#

Tags: c#

How can I convert  MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM  into DD/MM/YYYY using C# ?I am using C#2008.

Thanks

Comment: input and output and their types please... !

Comment: Look into `Date.ParseExact()`. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: can try String.Format().

Comment: And [Date.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=VS.90).aspx) with a format / culture specification.

Comment: Input datatype is string and output is database date(DT_DBDATE)

Comment: MSDN is your friend, get to know her: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `TryParseExact` to parse to a `DateTime`, then `ToString` with a format string to convert back...

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dt))
{
    string text = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Use text
}
else
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

Comment: Hi John, the second line, "Date" what it means? I'm getting error in this line. Could you help me to resolve this..

Comment: @Karthik: Just a typo - fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

As the time part is irrelevant, you can truncate that before parsing and re-formatting:

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, 10), "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

#### Edit:

As your comment reveals that you don't want a string as result, you should not format the date into a string, just get the date as a `DateTime` value:

```
Datetime dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date.Substring(0, 10), "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can use the `DateTime` value in your code, wrapping it in a database driver type if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a DateTime object, you should be able to just select a different format.

If it is a string, use the following:

```
public string convert(string date){
    string[] pieces = date.Split("/");
    string day = pieces[1];
    string month = pieces[0];
    string year = pieces[2].split(" ")[0];
    return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
}
```